# How To Loop Tasks In Discord.Py With Different Loops For Each Guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, discord, discord.py

I want to loop a task in Discord.py that will loop on several different guilds at different times. For example, if one guild calls this command at 20:00 and another guild calls the command at 13:00, I want to be able to run the command each day at the same time for each guild (at the time they specified). I also want those commands to reload when the server is restarted after maintenance.

So, basically, I want a certain command to run every day at different times for each server. I also want the timers to save so that they are there after a server restart.

The way I am doing this right now is by having an external database that stores all the necessary information required to run the command, loading that information on start up, and calling the async command on start up, basically reloading all the saved timers.

Here is the code I have thus far.

```
@commands.command(aliases=['dp'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dailyprompt(self, ctx, arbitrary_prefix, channel: discord.TextChannel, time_to_run: str, prompt=True):  # This command seriously needs a database to run more efficiently. For now though, I just want it working.

    if arbitrary_prefix.lower() == 'set' and channel is not None and time_to_run is not None:

        time_zone = pytz.timezone('EST')

        now = datetime.now(time_zone)
        datetime_to_run = f'{str(now.date())} {time_to_run}'
        datetime_to_run = datetime.strptime(datetime_to_run, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').astimezone(time_zone)
        difference = (datetime_to_run - now).total_seconds()

        if difference < 0:
            datetime_to_run += timedelta(hours=24)
            difference = (datetime_to_run - now).total_seconds()
            if difference < 0:
                await ctx.channel.send('Please input a valid time.')
                raise ValueError

            embed = discord.Embed(title='Daily Prompt Admin Notification', description=response, color=self.color)
            await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

        await asyncio.sleep(difference)
        await self.prompt(channel)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await self.dailyprompt(self, ctx, arbitrary_prefix, channel, time_to_run)
```

Comment: When your program loads info from the database, you could then sort the info by datetime_to_run and create an asyncio Task (see link below) for the first task, and wait for that to end before starting the next one.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks

Answer (score 1):

You should store data into a `.json` file, like this:

```
from json import load, dumps
global Path
Path = r"C:\\Path\to\File.json"
global Dictionary
Dictionary = {}
...
@Bot.command()
async def SetHour(ctx, hour:int):
    #Put there functions to make hour to be a datetime.data or datetime.time object
    global Dictionary
    Dictionary[ctx.guild.id] = hour
    DictionaryEncoded = dumps(Dictionary)
    Database = open(Path, 'w')
    Database.write(DictionaryEncoded)
    Database.close()
```

Did you need smth like this?

Comment: I already have a database for this and am doing something similar. I was simply looking to see if there was a better way, maybe something built natively into Discord.py that I missed that would simplify the task. Thank you though. Will upvote because it is a good answer.